# How do you have 2 order by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you have a single SQL that order events by current day then future dates and within current day and future dates in alphabetic order?

Please show me an example?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show it with an example of input data & how it should look like please?

Comment: Only a mentalist could answer this 100% correctly. The question lacks information.

Comment: I believe you are speaking of ordering using one date field in the way requested. Not ordering multiple fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY CASE WHEN date = CurrentDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,  AlphaField

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY Col1 ASC, Col2 DESC,...
```

Have a look at [ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

```
[ ORDER BY 
    {
    order_by_expression 
  [ COLLATE collation_name ] 
  [ ASC | DESC ] 
    } [ ,...n ] 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like:

```
where publishedAt>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP order by publishedAt asc, title asc
```

Comment: I think something like `>= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())` might be needed instead of `> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in order to get all events for the current day.